# Dynamically checking the multiple same naming variables with a number on the end

Tags: php, variables

I have about 15 variable with a same name and a number on the end.

For example `$Something1` `$Something2` `$Something3` ........

Before I use them I must check are they `null` or not.

I wrote some `for` loop for that. But it is not really good solution. Have a bad smell.

```php
for ($Something = 1; $Something < 16; $Something++){
    $SomethingNu = 'Something'.$Something;
        if($$SomethingNu === null){
            $$SomethingNu = 'some default value';
        }
}
```

I can do something like this. But also, it has a bad smell.

```php
if($Something1 === null){
    $Something1 = 'some default value';
}
if($Something2 === null){
    $Something2 = 'some default value';
}
if($Something3 === null){
    $Something3 = 'some default value';
}
.....
```

They will have the same default value if are they null `some default value` in this particular example.

My question is:

What is the best solution of doing that?

Comment: Can you change your variables for an array?

Comment: I wish I can...

Comment: Maybe explain how the variables are being used.

Comment: I found a better way of doing that. But this way is not related to this post. That's why I won't post it. I check each variable before I declare them with a null coalescing operator. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable parameter function that sets the default value for any number of variables you throw at it:

```
<?php

function var_checker(&...$vars) {
    foreach ($vars as $var_keys => &$var_var) {
        if ($var_var == NULL) {
            $var_var = "some default value";
        }

    }
}

$foobar = "something";
$foobar2 = NULL;

var_checker($foobar, $foobar2);

var_dump($foobar);
var_dump($foobar2);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "something"
string(18) "some default value"
```